# Excel Type Lookup using Workflows

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow

I am new to SharePoint workflows and looking for some help..
I am using Sharepoint 2010 with Designer 2010 and have two lists as below

List 1:

```
ItemID | Level | Status
10010 | Level 1 | Completed
10011 | Level 2 | Pending
```

List 2:

```
ItemID | Level | Status
 10010 | 
 10011 |
```

When some one updates the level & status in list 2 the workflow should update the respective records in the list 1 as well. I am restricted to use only custom workflows. Can anyone please help me with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To reflect your update ( level & status ) from list 2 to list 1 , try to use `Update List Item` Action at your custom workflow via SharePoint Designer as the following ,

- Open SharePoint Designer > click on  Workflow > from the above ribbon > select List Workflow And select your List 2.
- From the Above Ribbon, > Action > select `Update List Item`

[image]

- Click On this list.

[image]

- Select List 1 > click add.

[image]

- At `Set this field` > select the level at List 1 (level).
- At `to this value` > Click on fx button > select at the current item the Field Level.

[image]

- Repeat this for status field.
- At `find the list Item` > At Field select itemID > at Value set the ItemID as the following

[image]

- Make sure that you checked `start workflow automatically when an item is changed.`

[image]

- Save And Publish.